# Jtag Trace 32 - setting breakpoint in range of addresses

Tags: debugging, jtag

This is question on JTAG.

I am trying to set a read/write breakpoint in a range of addresses.

Command I give in b.set window is as follows(and selecting read/write)

```
A:0x8500000..0xd300000
```

But when i list it(b.list) it shows as follows :

```
AN:0x0:0x8500000--0xd300000
```

Why is 0x0 getting appended? So, is my original range of addresses at which i wanted to put the breakpoint is altered?

Additional Information : I am using Lauterbach Trace 32. CPU is ARm Krait

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x00 is the space ID. It is 0 for complete kernel space. For User spaces this space id is the process ID. Space Id's are nothing but Address space identifiers, used by TLB to differentiate the pagetable ebtries.